# Add new entry Entity framework many to many relationship mapping

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, mapping

I have following models: Which has many to many relationship.

```
 public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }        
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

    }

public class ProductCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string CategoryImgeUrl { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }
```

And I want to add new product with existing Categories , but when i add new product i also creates new Categories  too without using existing.

```
public void Add(ProductViewModel vm)
        {
            try
            {

                if (vm.SelectedCategoryIds.Count() != 0)
                {
                    var catList = new List<ProductCategoryViewModel>();
                    foreach (var item in vm.SelectedCategoryIds) {

                        var cat = Context.ProductCategories.Where(c=>c.Id == item).FirstOrDefault();
                        catList.Add(Mapper.Map<ProductCategoryViewModel>(cat));
                    }

                    vm.ProductCategories = catList;

                }
                var model = Mapper.Map<Product>(vm);
                model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                model.IsDeleted = false;
                Context.Products.Add(model);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Here i want to add new Product with existing Categories.
How can i sort this thing out ?

Comment: This is a very common problem of which you should be able to find many questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be

```
public void Add(ProductViewModel vm)
    {
        try {
            var model = Mapper.Map<Product>(vm);
            model.ProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>();
                //but this should be done by the Product ctor
            if (vm.SelectedCategoryIds.Count() != 0) {
                //var catList = new List<ProductCategoryViewModel>();
                foreach (var item in vm.SelectedCategoryIds) {
                    var cat = Context.ProductCategories.Where(c=>c.Id == item).FirstOrDefault();
                    if ( cat != null )
                        model.ProductCategories.Add(cat);
                    //catList.Add(Mapper.Map<ProductCategoryViewModel>(cat));
                }
                //vm.ProductCategories = catList;
            }
            //var model = Mapper.Map<Product>(vm);
            model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.IsDeleted = false;
            Context.Products.Add(model);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Please not that the foreach my be replaced by a single query

```
foreach (var item in Context.ProductCategories.
    Where(c=> vm.SelectedCategoryIds.Contains(c.Id))) 
{
    model.ProductCategories.Add(item);
}
```

Of course as suggested by Gert Arnold there are many variants, by example by using `Attach`....

Comment: not sure to understand.. are you looking for the upvote button ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your entities Product and ProductCategory classes are created with many to many relationship . Try this in ProductCategory and check

Try this :

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CategoryImgeUrl { get; set; }


    public Product Product { get; set; }

}
```